# How to implement three level cascading in SharePoint List using jquery

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have three columns in one list only, i want to implement cascading between three of them using jquery.

Fields are:

1. Family - Choice field
2. Category - single line of text
3. Sub-Category - single line of text

Task- when i select value from family, category should be filled with values otherwise no. Next i will select value from category, sub-category should be filled with values.

Would request everyone to help/guide me on this. Thank you in advance.

Regards

Ram

Comment: How would `Category` Column be filled with multiple values and how would you select one of them if you are going to use it as `Single Line of Text` Column?

Comment: Yes Yayati, you are true, but the same thing i have implemented in infopath, now i am developing the form using spforms with the same functionality. When it is possible in infopath, can't be done in spforms tool using jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 options for this

1.Use REST query to get data from SharePoint list, add it in object and show in dropdown list, for second dropdown, use first item as filter in REST query and so on ..

2.Second easiest option is to use SP Serivces.

***SPServices Cascading dropdown***

https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Second is not a dropdown sir, it is a single line of text. Thank you

Comment: kindly take a look at given url